# Unity WebPlayer not rendering canvas properly

Tags: canvas, rendering, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, unity-web-player

I was trying to modify Clip panel in Ortographic Camera for the 2D unity tutorial Roguelike, but suddenly after building it again the gameObjects in canvas show all white, like below:
[image]

The white box is supposed to be part of the gameboard as the tutorial shows. I reverted back the last change i made, but still the same, and now i can't find what happened here. Anybody that knows how to fix this? The Native PC build works fine by the way, only webplayer, and i need to use webplayer 'cause i have existing JS code to use with this.